# Could not find "store" in either the context

Tags: reactjs

Hi everyone I'm having this problem and I can't solve it right now.
I really need now that my app can call some api when it starts so I moved all my logic from the root to the app.
Does anyone know what is going on?

**index.js**

```
    import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM, {render} from "react-dom";
import App from './App';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/rootReducer";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { save } from "redux-localstorage-simple";
//CONSTS
const css = require("./App.scss");
const middlewares = [thunk];
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares, save()))
  );
const RootApp = () => (
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)
ReactDOM.render(<RootApp />, document.getElementById('App'));
```

**App.js**

```
 // IMPORTS
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import HomeComponent from "./pages/Home.js";
import DetailComponent from "./pages/Detail.js";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { getItems } from "./store/actions";
class App extends Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    await getItems()
    //this.setState({ items });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent} />
          <Route exact path="/:id" component={DetailComponent} />
        </Switch>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({getItems},dispatch);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

**html**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

        <div id='App'>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm getting this error

*browser.js:38 Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)".*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually using the correct rendering:

---

### Your code

1. You don't render your application wrapped by `Provider`, nor `Router` but `App` directly (check your `ReactDOM.render(...)` line);
2. You are attempting to mount your React application on a non DOM element... (same line, second argument).

```
// lots of imports ...

import ReactDOM, {render} from "react-dom";

// You mount App here...
// On something that should have an id `App` in your DOM...
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('App'));

// Then you create your store... But it's too late already!

//CONSTS
const css = require("./App.scss");
const middlewares = [thunk];
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares, save()))
  );


render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);
```

---

### Fix

You could try the following:

```
// ... Imports and stuff

const store = createStore( /* ... and stuff again ... */ );

const RootApp = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<RootApp />, document.getElementById('react-root'));

// And would probably be a good idea that this line is
// the last one of your file.
```

And in your `index.html`:

```
<body>
  <div id="react-root"></div>

  <!-- other stuff ... -->
</body>
```

Comment: now it's says  Target container is not a DOM element.

Comment: Hmmm. I actually didn't check, I'll edit my answer And it would be nice if you could paste your `index.html` too. This last error is coming from there :)

Comment: You have 2 closing `</div>`s... Confuses the DOM I guess.

Comment: I meant you have two closing `div`s in you `index.html`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181025/discussion-between-nohoney-k1ll-and-leopold-houdin).